# Problem with command : ld when Exploring System Calls with Assembly Language

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I have a job to do where I have to write Hello world and Goodbye world with assembler.

Here's my code:

```
section .data
    hello db 'Hello, World!',0   ; The first string to be printed, terminated with a null character (0)
    goodbye db 'Goodbye, World!',0 ; The second string to be printed, terminated with a null character (0)
    newline db 10,0             ; Newline character and null terminator (10 is the ASCII code for newline)

section .text
global _start

_start:
    ; Call the _main function
    call _main

    ; Exit the program
    mov rax, 0x2000001         ; syscall number for exit (1)
    xor rdi, rdi               ; exit status, 0
    syscall

_main:
    ; Write the first message to stdout (file descriptor 1)
    mov rax, 0x2000004         ; syscall number for write (4)
    mov rdi, 1                 ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    lea rsi, [rel hello]       ; pointer to the first message string
    mov rdx, 13                ; length of the first message
    syscall

    ; Write a newline character
    mov rax, 0x2000004         ; syscall number for write (4)
    mov rdi, 1                 ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    lea rsi, [rel newline]     ; pointer to the newline character
    mov rdx, 1                 ; length of the newline character
    syscall

    ; Write the second message to stdout (file descriptor 1)
    mov rax, 0x2000004         ; syscall number for write (4)
    mov rdi, 1                 ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    lea rsi, [rel goodbye]     ; pointer to the second message string
    mov rdx, 14                ; length of the second message
    syscall

    ret
```

the name of my document is assembleur.asm

I then ran the command: `nasm -f macho64 -o assembler.o assembler.asm`

an assembler.o file is created

I then run the command: `ld -e _start -macos_version_min 10.7.0 -o assembler assembler.o`

```
and then I get an error: ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/Users/me/Desktop/OS/assembleur.o', assuming: macOS
ld: Undefined symbols:
  dyld_stub_binder, referenced from:
      <initial-undefines>
```

do you know how to help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `ld  -dynamic -e _start -macos_version_min 10.7.0 -o assembler assembler.o -lSystem`

Comment: thank you for your reply, I now have the error: `ld: library 'System' not found`

Comment: Find out where you have it installed and pass the directory using a `-L` option. Could be something like `-L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib`

Comment: Have you installed `Command Line Tools` ? https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/index.html

Comment: Normally you'd just put the newline at the end of the `hello` string instead of making a separate `write` system call for it.  And you'd also want one at the end of the `goodbye` string; some shells print the prompt wherever a program leaves the cursor, so it looks messy.  Also, the `0` terminators aren't useful for write system calls: it takes a pointer and length of a buffer of bytes, not looking for a terminating `0`.  (read and write system calls work with arbitrary binary data, including zero bytes; that's why they use length args and return values.)